# How to avoid listing FIELD/IN twice?

Tags: mysql

I have `SELECT field(foo,'this','that','bar','baz') FROM t WHERE f1 IN ('this','that','bar','baz')` How can I avoid listing `('this','that','bar','baz')` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [**FIELD function's return value**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field) and make sure it is not zero:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *,field(foo,'this','that','bar','baz') fieldfoo FROM t) A
WHERE fieldfoo > 0;
```

Comment: OK that avoids the strings but still requires writing out N "things" for N strings.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Ah yes! `FIELD` is 1-indexed and returns 0 for anything not found, indeed. Nice trick.